# sqlplus - executing single statement

Tags: sql, sqlplus

Currently I am executing Linux commands in Perl using the system command.

I have the working line 'sqlplus username/password@url @test.sql'

Is there any possible way to execute a single SQL statement instead of the SQL statements inside the test.sql file?

e.g.

```
'sqlplus username/password@url select * from TableA'
```

Comment: Other than piping the statement to SQLPlus?  Can't you just say $ echo "select * from TableA;" | sqlplus username/password@url . Or are you trying to save (spool) the results into a text file?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use Perl DBI and DBD for Oracle. This allows you to declare SQL statements and process the results as rowsets, instead of the rather primitive (and somewhat slower) method of processing output from sqlplus.

Link to [DBD](http://search.cpan.org/~pythian/DBD-Oracle-1.68/lib/DBD/Oracle.pm)
Link to [DBI](http://dbi.perl.org/)
Quick primer [Example](http://thomas.eibner.dk/oracle/dbi/)